# Error when connecting to oracle database in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

This is my code when run in pyspark env(version spark 3.1.2):

> jdbcDF = spark.read \
>
> ```
> .format("jdbc") \
>
> .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.1.1:1521/sbank") \
>
> .option("dbtable", "sa.a") \
>
> .option("user", "g") \
>
> .option("password", "zxc") \
>
> .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
>
> .load()
> ```

**But shows the announcement below as:**

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_29/4076487584.py in <module>
----> 1 jdbcDF = spark.read \
      2     .format("jdbc") \
      3     .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.0.1.1:1521/sbank") \
      4     .option("dbtable", "sa.a") \
      5     .option("user", "g") \

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    208             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    209         else:
--> 210             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    211 
    212     def json(self, path, schema=None, primitivesAsString=None, prefersDecimal=None,

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o137.load
```

Can anyone help me to solve that? Thank you in advance.

I add ojdbc11.jar into jars forder of spark

Comment: are you able to ping or access oracle host from spark cluster

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve that?

Comment: Did you get ping response